# DHCP settings not taking

Tags: networking, dhcp

I am woring on setting up a VLAN for my home network, I have been using dhcpd on a rasbery pi as my DHCP server.  I have setup in my network router DHCP Relay.  This is so far working for my work laptop, I have VLANed it to it own network.  But now I want to move my game consoles to their own VLAN (not mac addresses redacted)

```
subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    ddns-updates on;
    range 192.168.42.100 192.168.42.254;
    option routers 192.168.42.1;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.42.255;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.42.206;
 }
```

My work VLAN setting in the DHCP server are as follow

```
subnet 192.169.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    authoritative;
    ddns-updates on;
    range 192.169.42.10 192.169.42.20;
    option routers 192.169.42.1;
    option broadcast-address 192.169.42.255;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.42.206;
    host WORKLAPTOP {
            hardware ethernet xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;
    }
}
```

But my settings for my game consoles is not working this is what I have

```
## Game Network                                                                 
subnet 192.170.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    authoritative;
    ddns-updates on;
    range 192.170.42.100 192.170.42.200;
    option routers 192.170.42.1;
    option broadcast-address 192.170.42.255;
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
    # XBOX                                                                  
    host XBOX {
         hardware ethernet xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;
    }

 }
```

But when the xbox does the DHCP request it gets back
the IP address : 192.168.42.231
router address : 192.170.42.1
and DNS server : 8.8.8.8

is there anything I have done wrong with the configuration of the gameing Network settings? why is it getting the PI in the 192.168.x.x instead of the 192.170.x.x area, the router and the DNS server is set correctly

I am hoping to figure this thing out as I would like to setup a VLAN for my IoT of things for security reasons, I am testing it on other devices first.

I will note that the work laptop is working correctly it gets the
IP : 192.169.42.10
router :  192.169.42.1
DNS : 192.168.42.206

And I can not find what the diff between the work config and the Game Console config is.

I have already created the VLANs on my network
Work Lan is VLAN10, game network VLAN is 30 (going to use 20 for the IoT when I figure this all out, also using Unifi for the managed switches and access points)

Both VLANs have DHCP Relay on.  Using the Unifi USG for the router.

Comment: I would try swapping the worklaptop to the game vlan - just to make sure it works as expected. This could help debug if there is something incorrect (like mac for xbox is not right) - I would try the swapt first, see if the work laptop moves to 170 network.

Comment: 1) sorry on the lateness of my response 2) sadly that did not work 3) I found a work around,  For the longest time I was doing the DHCP on a Rasberry Pi as I wanted to move my network config off of the ISP router.  But between that time and now I got a Unifi router,  so the reason to move it to the Pi does not exist anymore, so I am moving the DHCP to the Router, and that has fixed the issue with the xbox not taking (and makes things simpler to get running)  
While it does not fix the problem above it fixes MY problem.  But thanks for trying to help.